# Windows Desktop Randomly Switches Resolution

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, resolution, switch

Once per log in a specific account, Windows XP is switching to 800x600 and 8 (looks like) bit color. It then after a few seconds switches back to the regular settings.

This, so far, has only happened, once per log in session but it is becoming very annoying for the end user. :P

Any ideas? I've tried turning off hardware acceleration as well as getting rid of her picture desktop wallpaper but nothing has made a difference.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's trying to auto-detect the monitor resolution. Is the account mobile, or is the user using a laptop?

Comment: It is not a roaming profile or a laptop.

Comment: @bobber205: When you check display settings, does it describe your monitor by name, or is it "generic"?

Comment: Generic I believe.

Comment: @Bobber205: Try finding the disk for the monitor, and loading the config. That might fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen with curtain users, or does it happen with administrators?

Comment: So far with just one account.

Comment: well i would make give that account admin rights and login, if it is trying to detect a monitor for whatever reason it wont save its findings unless its an admin.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you grab a copy of [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and see what is running at startup. Your description suggests to me that something is starting which changes the screen resolution, which then changes back when that program exits. You may need to use a bit of trial and error, disabling startup items until the offender is located.